# Get records between two days which are selected by two datetimepickers and fill a datagridview with them in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataset, datetimepicker

This is my code:

This is in a different class named `DBAccess`

```
public DataSet getRecords(DateTime dtpFloor,DateTime dtpCeiling)
{

   if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

   SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

   newCmd.Connection = conn;

   newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   newCmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM dbo.ClientInvoice  WHERE invDate BETWEEN  '" + dtpCeiling + "' AND  '" + dtpFloor + "'";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(newCmd);

            DataSet dsIncome = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(dsIncome, "Client");

             conn.Close();

            return dsIncome;

}
```

Below Coding is in the ProfitLos form class

```
public void btnClickFillGrid()
{

    DataSet dsIncome =     dba.getRecords(dtpFloor.Value.ToString(),    dtpCeiling.Value.ToString()); //dba is an object of DBAccess class

    dgvproIncome.DataSource = dsIncome.Tables["Client"].DefaultView;

}
```

`btnClickFillGrid()` will invoke at the button click event.

In the database - invdate datetime;(invDate is the variable name and its in the datetime format)

i edited my coding like this

```
public DataSet getRecords(DateTime dtpFloor,DateTime dtpCeiling)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KOSHITHA-PC;Initial Catalog=ITP;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                 conn.Open();
                 using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                 {
                     string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ClientInvoice WHERE invDate BETWEEN" + "@from AND @to"; 
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from",dtpFloor);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dtpCeiling);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet dataSetClient = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dataSetClient, "Client");
            return dataSetClient;
                }
            }
        }


DataSet dataSetClient = dba.getRecords(dtpFloor.Value, dtpCeiling.Value);
                dgvproIncome.DataSource = dataSetClient.Tables["Client"].DefaultView;
```

now i m getting an exception in "da.Fill(dataSetClient, "Client");" line saying 
sqlException was unhandled
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BETWEEN@from'.

i m not familiar with the parameter passing method to sql query,so couldnt find the problem that i m having

Comment: this code is not working (obviously)and shows exceptions..

Comment: Actually, that code won't even compile - see my answer.

Comment: so what and where is the problem?

Comment: then provide the exception messages... another point: your usage of SQL without parameters is extremely dangerous since it is prone to SQL injection which is a serious security issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this call:

```
dba.getRecords(dtpFloor.Value.ToString(), dtpCeiling.Value.ToString());
```

That's clearly passing in *strings* as the arguments. Now look at your method declaration:

public DataSet getRecords(DateTime dtpFloor,DateTime dtpCeiling)

Those parameters are of type `DateTime`, not string. So the first thing to fix is the call, to:

```
dba.getRecords(dtpFloor.Value, dtpCeiling.Value);
```

Now the *next* problem is that you're embedding the values in the SQL directly. Don't do that. *Never* do that. In some cases it can lead to SQL injection attacks, and in other cases it causes data conversion issues (as you've got here). Use parameterized SQL instead - oh, and use connection pooling rather than trying to use a single connection in multiple places:

```
public DataSet GetRecords(DateTime dtpFloor,DateTime dtpCeiling)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ClientInvoice WHERE invDate BETWEEN "
                       + "@from AND @to";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", dtpFloor");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dtpCeiling");

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dataSet, "Client");
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an sql exception coming with this coding..i m not sure why...i edited my coding as you have mentioned above..

Comment: @koshi18: You need to *read* the exception. I'd just missed out a space between "BETWEEN" and "@from" - look at the exception closely.